# How is my question unclear?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

This is my question: [How to programmatically include a file in my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544354/how-to-programmatically-include-a-file-in-my-project)

It is based on this other question: [Include in project programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15180527/include-in-project-programmatically)

In my C# question I link to the other VB question asking for assistance with its only solution that doesn't work for me. The other question has almost no text, but it's fine. My question has some background, explanation why the other question's solution doesn't work, and yet it's closed as unclear. I even edited it to include the screenshot from the other question.

What am I doing wrong? How can I further improve my question to be able to get answers?

Comment: Not related, but I find updated posts that make use of "Edit", "Update", and phrases like "for those who still don't understand what I'm asking" are not easy to read.  When you edit, you should write the question like no one has read it and not just append changes to the end.  There are occasionally times you need to do it but I don't think this is one of those times.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that way I was trying to save the question from being closed as unclear, which, as you can see, failed. I will re-edit the question to be as you said, as it's the right way to go.

Comment: I do understand why, but often I think it makes it less clear because I get halfway through a post and then find new "clarification" so I have to go back and figure out how the clarification fits with what I already read.  Just my opinion though - others might disagree.

Comment: @psubsee2003 no, no, you're absolutely correct on this one. I even think this should be written somewhere in the editing guidelines for questions that are closed as unclear, because it really does make for additional confusion. By the way I edited my original question.

Comment: I saw it and I voted to reopen.  One other thing that I think would help is explaining in more detail why you couldn't find Microsoft.Build.  You mention it in your comments, but I think that is important to providing you a solution (as I am about to comment on your question)

Comment: @psubsee2003 It's just not there. I don't know where to look for it. Not sure if there's anything I can add about that.

Comment: I found it by searching my hard drive.  Not everything is in "Add Reference/.NET".

Comment: As such, your question is indeed a dup.  If it gets reopened, I'd suggest you vote to close it as a dup of the VB solution you found.

Comment: @psubsee2003 why not do the other way around? I bet my question will have a more detailed answer. Or is it that the other question was posted earlier?

Comment: Not because it is older, but the reason is the other question already has a correct answer.  The fact that you were targeting the wrong framework doesn't change that the answer there was correct.  But adding a more detailed answer on how to reference `Microsoft.Build` might be in order.  Since you have your answer now, I'd suggest writing it up (with screenshots) as that answer.

Comment: @psubsee2003 ok, I get it now. But before closing it again the moment it gets opened I'd like to actually know an answer to my question. As it is now, the other question only says what method to use, but not how it is used, so it's of little use to me, except I might be able to ask a new question with this new knowledge. What would you recommend to do?

Comment: Well, that's a different question than what you asked.  I think you need to make an attempt and then ask a new question if you run into problems

Answer (score 5):

The biggest issue with your edited question is you do not explain in enough detail why the solutions in the linked question do not work.  Just saying "it doesn't work" is enough to enrage most experienced users as there could be dozens of reasons it doesn't work.  Had you explained why `Microsoft.Build` didn't work after the edit (and what you tried to do to make it work), then someone would have help you find it and target the proper framework yesterday.

In fact, [paqogomez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544354/how-to-programmatically-include-a-file-in-my-project#comment27277634_18544354)'s comment was already going in that direction but no one really followed up on that line of thinking.

Personally, I think the question should be closed as a dup of the vb question you linked, and even though I voted to reopen since I think it is almost clear enough, I am going to vote to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: [I did say in the first revision of my question](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/18544354/1) that I couldn't find the library I need to reference to make it work.

Comment: @user1306322 sorry, missed that, I only saw the editted question

Answer (score -5):

Either it was voted closed before you edited it to clear things up, or people were in a rush to flag it to get a new shiny gold badge. ATM, I see nothing wrong with it other than the fact that there is no code involved. Perhaps another exchange site would be more appropriate?

Comment: "No code involved" does not automatically make it off-topic. I doubt this would be on-topic anywhere but Stack Overflow.